# Is it needed to delete unused new structs within a function?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to improve my C++, so I decided to start fresh and went through a few tutorials.

It seems to be a general rule that each "new" operation has to be followed by "delete" eventually, to avoid risking a memory leak.

Then, I stumbled across the following code segment on a [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/a-comprehensive-guide-to-implementation-of-singly-linked-list-using-c_plus_plus-ondlm5azr) regarding linked lists:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class linkedlist {
    private:
        node* head;
        node* tail;
    public:
        linkedlist(){
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }

        void delete_first()
        {
            node *temp=new node;
            temp=head;
            head=head->next;
            delete temp;
        }

        // additional functions for add/delete/display, ...
}
```

The problem I'm having here, is understanding the delete_first() function completely.

1. Create a new node in dynamic memory and assign it to 'temp'
2. Set temp's pointer to now point at the head instead (but what happened to the new node?)
3. Make the head's subsequent element the new head
4. Delete temp from memory

I assume that the tutorial would not introduce memory leaks, but it certainly seems to me as if each call of delete_first() would generate an extra struct that's never deleted.

Okay, there's both a 'new' and a 'delete', but wouldn't that suggest that the amount of elements in memory stays the same?

Could anybody please clear me up and elaborate why there's no(?) memory leak happening in this case?

Comment: If you found this snipped in a tutorial: Run. Run as fast as you can, and grab a good c++ book.

Comment: Report the problem to the author… Definitively incorrect code that leaks.

Comment: Better advice for modern C++: avoid using `new` and `delete` entirely.

Comment: The tutorial does the exact same mistake in almost every single method. Seems like the author should themself read a good C++ book before trying to teach.

Comment: Is this a tutorial that is intended to teach you how to find bugs in code, and debug them?  If so, it seems like a fantastic tutorial.

Comment: Thank you. I was seriously worried that I completely misunderstood memory allocation! I will try to find better learning material.

Comment: Use containers and smart pointers. Not manual memory management.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'm aware that there's a lot of efficient implementations for various containers (including a linked list) - my objective here is to learn how to program at a low level to find out how things work, not to create a larger project, where the use of libraries from people who know what they're doing would be the better choice for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

That’s a bug in the tutorial you were reading. It shouldn’t be creating a new node in `delete_first()`. Instead, it should be setting `temp` to `head` when it’s declared.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, that makes perfect sense. I really like the idea of initializing the variable by pointing it to an already existing element :)